# How to fetch a new result from MySQL during every loop with a keyword?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL, so I've gotten a bit confused here. What I'm doing right now is calling a Mysql query that fetches data from a table where a keyword is matched. The code is right here:

```
public function fetch_tags($tag) {
    global $pdo; 

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `articles`  WHERE `article_tags` LIKE '%$tag%' OR `article_content` LIKE '%$tag%'"); 

    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetch();
}
```

The problem is that say the keyword passed in first is "Michael", and then the next one is "Dekstra," both of these will return the exact same row because they are the first and last name of the same person. I don't want to fetch the same result twice though. How can I make it so that once a particular result has been fetched, the next query won't go in to get the same result again. They need to be different every single time. I want them ordered from newest to oldest.

Any help is much appreciated. I feel really lost.

Comment: Please tell us a little more about the overall goal here, it's unclear how or why you are using a loop for this. You can (and should) fetch an ordered set of rows with just one query.

Comment: So is there anyway that I could perhaps add a parameter telling it not to fetch previously gotten results?

Comment: Define "previously gotten" results.

Comment: @AirThomas right now, all I'm doing to hold these results is using a $variable = $article->fetch_tags($word); however, this method does not give me a way of keeping track of ones that I've ALREADY fetched. Make sense?

Comment: I got away with this by ordering it by random, but I can no longer afford to do that.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using [`fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) and `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can add a `$blacklist` parameter, which will contain an array of IDs of rows already fetched and add it to your query: `WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3)`.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit? I've been using MySQL for like a couple of days. I get what you're saying, but how would that kind of look like?

Comment: @Vimzy i never used native PDO, so i cant help you with using it :( but if i was creating standart SQL query, i would use something like `"WHERE id NOT IN (".implode(",", $blacklist).")"`